# Travelling from Berlin Airport to Leipzig

Tags: trains, berlin, leipzig

I am flying to Berlin Tegel Airport (TXL). I need to get to Leipzig. Is it possible to get a train from the Airport? Or do I have to get a connection train? I read something about Rail& Fly. But I am not really sure about the train from Berlin I will be carrying luggage, which will be relatively heavy (~30KG)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Berlin, the bigger problem is that there is no long-distance train station in any of the airports. In spite of [the official website's rhetoric](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-txl/to-and-from/buses-and-trains/local-public-transport/index.php), Tegel is actually relatively poorly connected to the local and national transport networks, you need to take a bus to get anywhere, there isn't even a good S-Bahn or U-Bahn connection. Since it's much closer to the center of the city than many other airports, it's not that bad but you do need to get at least one bus connection.

Once you get to one of Berlin's major train stations (e.g. the new “Hauptbahnhof”), you can easily catch a direct train to Leipzig, possibly with a Rail&Fly ticket. [Rail&Fly](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/flug/rail_und_fly.shtml) fares can only be booked through your airline but if there is a train, you can always take it with a regular train ticket as well, you don't necessarily need Rail&Fly or any other special fare.

Incidentally, Tegel was slated to be closed some time ago but Berlin's new airport (built around the old Schönefeld airport) also had many problems with it's connection to the rail network and isn't even operating yet, several years after the planned opening so Berlin is a very poor choice if you are looking for an easy train connection.

Comment: Thank you. I just saw a route on google maps. The route looks to be operated by vbb.de  Is this the bus you mentioned?

Comment: @jogabonito Yes. You can find more details by following the link to the airport's website.

Comment: Is it practical to get on the bus/es with luggage?

Comment: @jogabonito I don't quite remember. It should be a [city bus like this one](http://media.oh-world.com/r/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Bus-TXL-de-Tegel-a-la-Hauptbahnhof-by-galio-300x225.jpg?q=95&d=blog.gowithoh.com) (not a long-distance coach) so it's a hassle but it's doable (no long stairs or narrow aisles, you can sit with your luggage).

Comment: [Rail&Fly](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/flug/rail_und_fly.shtml) is a service offered by Deutsche Bahn and many airlines which allows to use almost any train on the German rail network to reach your final destination. Rail&Fly is often significantly cheaper than buying your ticket directly from Deutsche Bahn. However you are still on your own risk, e.g. if you miss a connection.

Comment: You seem to confuse this offer with [AIRail](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/prices/germany/airail.shtml) which are trains operated as a Lufthansa codeshare and abide the same regulation as regular flights in case of delay. There is also no connection from/to Leipzig or Berlin.

Comment: The busses that run to Tegel airport are regular low-floor city busses with less seats and more space for luggage. It is definitely usable, in fact many travelers use this bus service. From Hauptbahnhof (which can be reached by bus line *TXL*) there is a direct connection to Leipzig.

Comment: "In spite of the official website's rhetoric, Tegel is actually relatively poorly connected to the local and national transport networks" indeed and nicely put.

Comment: @neo Yes, it's possible, either way it's not relevant, I amended the answer.

Comment: @Relaxed Sure it's relevant. If jogabonito's airline offers Rail&Fly it is most likely cheaper than booking directly at Deutsche Bahn.

Comment: @neo But there is no train station in Berlin-Tegel and you just wrote yourself that it wasn't relevant!?

Comment: @Relaxed Most airlines that land in Berlin-Tegel offer Rail&Fly tickets starting at "Berlin" (which can mean any Berlin train station). So this is indeed relevant.

Comment: @neo I see. It's your comment that there was “also” no connection from/to Leipzig or Berlin that misled me.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the "Hauptbahnhof" from Tegel by riding the TXL-Bus (public transportation) which runs every 5 minutes. The fare is about 2.7€ and it will take about 15-20 minutes. 
Take a direct train to Leipzig from there. This is the Link to the german railway authority called [Deutsche Bahn](http://www.deutschebahn.com/en/start.html)