# Travelling from Frankfurt airport to Leipzig by train

Tags: trains, leipzig, frankfurt

As a kind of follow up to [Travelling from Berlin Airport to Leipzig](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35638/travelling-from-berlin-airport-to-leipzig), I have decided to take the train from Frankfurt to Leipzig.

I believe that the station at the airport is frankfurt main flugh
I see that tickets are cheaper if I book "Saving Fare" which means that I have to travel by a specific train.
I would like to know what the rates will be if I try to buy tickets at the airport station?
Also if I buy online, do I have to do anything with the ticket print out at the station? ( validate/exchange for a boarding pass?)

Comment: If you are arriving by plane, do you really want to commit yourself to a specific train?

Comment: Once I flew into Frankfurt, having bought a "Saving Fare" train ticket to Bonn in advance. My flight was late and I missed my train and had to change my reservation. I had to pay some extra, but not a whole new ticket, I think it was just the difference between the "Saving Fare" and the last-minute fare. So, I would recommend buying in advance.

Comment: Yes, you have to pay the difference between standard and savings fare plus 15€. If you pay in the train (rather than at the station) an additional 7,50€ surcharge applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, the station at Frankfurt airport is called *Frankfurt(M)Flughafen*. It is divided into two parts called *Frankfurt(M) Flughafen Fernbf* (for intercity trains) and *Frankfurt(M) Flughafen Regionalbf* (for regional trains). The DB website will recommend whatever option is best for you when you enter *Frankfurt(M)Flughafen* (most likely the *Fernbf*).

You can buy a ticket directly at the station for the *Standard fare* shown online. It is at the moment 76€ or 81€ depending on whether you want to be able to take an ICE train or not. The ticket is valid for any train for the day booked and the following day.

If you book an online ticket you don't need to do anything with it at the station, you can just board your train. It is advisable to have a printout of the ticket, [but not mandatory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26186/pdf-tickets-on-phone-on-deutsche-bahn/34233#34233).

When using an online ticket you need to have an identification card which you need to enter while booking and show the conductor when traveling. [This can be any of the following](https://www.bahn.de/i/view/GBR/en/prices/onlineticket/onlineticket.shtml):

> An identification card (BahnCard, bahn.bonus Card, credit cards*, ec-card/Maestro or ID
>   card**) for booking via Internet and as identification during fare
>   controls on the train.
>
> [...]
>
> * American Express, MasterCard, Diners Club, Visa or JCB
>
> ** The ID cards of the following countries can be used as identification on the train: Germany, Austria, Switzerland, France,
>   the Netherlands, Belgium, Luxembourg, Italy and the Czech Republic.
>
> Please note:
>
> - Passports are not accepted as identification documents.
> - For identification with ec-cards/Maestro, your bank must have its registered office in Germany.

Comment: I decided to buy the standard fare. It is an ICE train, but I  understand that I am allowed to board any train that direction that day, Is this only for ICE trains or can I board an IC train

Comment: Yes, you can take an IC train, too. Any connection in the same direction will be fine. If you are unsure, you can buy your ticket at the station for the same price.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, *Frankfurt (M) Flughafen* is the Airport railway station.
It is very easy to get there, from Terminal 1, just 10 min walking, just follow the signs.

Normally, if you buy your tickets online at [bahn.de](http://bahn.de) 2-3 weeks before your trip, you can get a 29€ ticket.

The prices are depending on the train type:

*ICE*: (InterCityExpress) very fast train, less stops, train restaurant -> pricy

*IC*: (InterCity) Regional Train, more stops, train bistro

*RE*: (Regional Express) very slow train, many stops in small cities -> less pricy

If you book online you can pay with a Credit Card. You have to personalize your ticket (name, age, telephone number etc). You have to verify your identity with a creditcard or ID.

You have to print your online ticket. The printed ticket is as valid as the "official" ticket from the counter/ticket machine. You have to bring the ticket and the document you decided to identify with (Creditcards, Maestro, ID, etc).
They often are accepting online tickets on smartphones, iPad, etc.

If you buy your ticket at the station, it will be 3 times pricier.

If you don't want to plan for 2 weeks, there is a last-minute option: [ltur.de](http://www.ltur.com/de/bahn.html?omnin=TopNavi-DB)
On this site you can find 27€ tickets from 1 day to 1 week before your trip. If the tickets are gone, they are gone. This website is using the same interface as bahn.de

Comment: For the completeness of this answer, it should be added that the OP's statement "I see that tickets are cheaper if I book "Saving Fare" which means that I have to travel by a specific train." is *correct*, i.e., he has to use the trains stated on the ticket if she/he buys a cheaper one. So if the plane is delayed, the ticket is almost void (AFAIK, its value can be used on the same day as a started for buying a full-flexible ticket for the same route at the counter, but minus 15 Euro processing fee, though). Some exceptions apply (regional trains, certain train delays allow to travel later).

Comment: It should also be noted that whether "Normally, if you buy your tickets online at bahn.de 2-3 weeks before your trip, you can get a 29€ ticket" holds depends heavily on the route. On Sundays and Fridays, for trains from Frankfurt Airport going to Leipzig starting between 11:00 and 18:00, for example, it is rather unlikely to hold.